# Laravael 5.2 how get url?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Tell me please, how get URL on view with Url::asset?

Try:

```
<p>TEXT 
<a href="http://{{ $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] }}/dir/file.pdf" target="_blank">TEXT_LINK</a>
TEXT</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just -

`<a href= "{{ URL::asset('dir/file.pdf') }}" target="_blank">TEXT_LINK</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a href= "{{ resource_path('assets/dir/file.pdf') }}" target="_blank">TEXT_LINK</a>
```

(if your dir is in assets)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-resource-path

Comment: As an option, you can still public_path (), but i need get with Url::asset